# How do I loop through get-counter results to get to make a decision?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to get the following counter over the span of 5 minutes.  If it returns 100, 5 times in a row, I'd like to receive an email.

```
get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 60 -MaxSamples 5
```

I've tried to assign that block of code to a variable, so for example:

```
$value = get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 60 -MaxSamples 5

if($value eq 100)
{
  $counter = $counter + 1
}

if($counter > 4)
{
"send an email"
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the actual counter value to get assigned to the $value variable.  Furthermore I'd like the counter to increment every time the code fires (before it hits the maxsamples value).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
$value = get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5
$Total = $Value | % { $_.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue } | Measure -Sum;

if ($Total.Sum -ge 490) {
    # Total CPU usage was 490+
}
```

Or, if you want to do it in context of percentages, do this:

```
$value = get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5
$Total = $Value | % { $_.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue } | Measure -Average;

if ($Total.Average -ge 95) {
    # Total CPU usage was 95%+
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-Counter returns an array of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSampleSet` type so you have to work with it as follows:

a little bit more generic solution:

```
$sampleInterval = 60 # in seconds
$samples = 50 # samples taken
$inRowSamples = 5 # 5 samples in a row
$shouldntExceed = 0.95 # 95%

$values = get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval $sampleInterval -MaxSamples $samples

$count = 0
foreach ($value in $values)
{
    if ($value.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue -gt $shouldntExceed)
    {
        $count++;
    }
    else
    {
        $count = 0;
    }

    if ($count -ge $inRowSamples)
    {
        # send email
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys.  I think Tomas' answer is closer to what I need but I knew there was something I was missing.  I need to look into the structure more, and how the CookedValue works.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$maxCount = 5;
$maxValue = 100;
$count = 0;
get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 | %{

    if($_.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue -ge $maxValue){
        $count++;
    }
    #handling the n times in a row condition
    else{
        $count=0
    }
    if($count -eq $maxCount){
        write-host "exceeded"
        #send email
        break
    }

}
```

Since we are using pipeline, the above will send email as soon as you have 5 continuous values greater than or equal to 100.

Comment: You need to change the -MaxSamples parameter for -Continuous, otherwise you'll only alert if the counter exceeds the limit in the first N intervals after starting, as will the previous suggestions.